# How can I set tmux hotkey as Ctrl-, that is, Ctrl+comma

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, tmux, hotkeys

I've got some trouble when setting my preferred tmux hotkey on Mac OS X.

The most common hotkeys that invokes tmux's magics are <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>. But I would rather select other keystrokes for the following reasons: C-a is the global hot key for "jumping to the beginning of a line"; <kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>b</kbd> is for "moving backward on a line" and "Page UP in Vim". I don't want to break these nice rules in tmux.

So, I try to set some non-so-frequently-used keystrokes for tmux hotkey. What I choose is <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>,</kbd> , <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>.</kbd>, or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>;</kbd>

I write this statement in my .tmux.conf file:

```
set-option -g prefix C-,
```

I start tmux. Oh, it says "bad key". I replace C-, with C-. or C-;. It doesn't work either.

So, how can I set tmux hotkey to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>,</kbd>?

Comment: Related Super User question: [How do I bind the tmux prefix key to C-'?](http://superuser.com/q/395233/14827)

Comment: precisely for the reasons you mentioned i'm using CTRL-T in my screen config. I'm not using taglists in vim. (CTRL-T - jump backward in taglist)

Answer (score 15):

Had to dig into the source code for this one. The control key can only be applied to letters, @, space and ? (and C-@ seems to be equivalent to C-space). Sorry, doesn't look like C-, is possible, at least in tmux-1.6.

Comment: chepner, thank for your answer. Sound like bad news. It means that no REAL solution is available recently. I will make a compromise to use C-q, C-h or C-z. I guess there should be some keystrokes which aren't occupied by emacs, vim, or other things.

Comment: Not sure what you mean with 'letters'. But the backslash is a valid (although tricky to set, see http://superuser.com/q/417236/63972) combination with C-.

Answer (score 8):

None of comma, period, or semicolon are standard control characters. Your terminal emulator probably just sends the plain character, or nothing at all when you type them; you can type them at into `cat -v` to see what it is sending.

See Wikipedia’s “[ASCII control characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_control_characters)” and “[How control characters map to keyboards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character#How_control_characters_map_to_keyboards)”.

If you can reconfigure your terminal emulator to send some other character/sequence, you should be able to use it in *tmux* (e.g. have your terminal emulator send the same character as `C-\` (hex 1C), and set your prefix to that).

Answer (score 4):

Using xterm terminal

1) put these in your `~/.Xresources` to generate escape sequence of <kbd>F13</kbd> when <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>,</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>.</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>;</kbd> is pressed

```
XTerm.VT100.translations: #override \                                                                                                   
    Ctrl<Key>period:    string(0x1b) string("[1;2P") \n\                                                                                
    Ctrl<Key>comma:    string(0x1b) string("[1;2P") \n\                                                                                 
    Ctrl<Key>semicolon:    string(0x1b) string("[1;2P")
```

run `xrdb ~/.Xresources` to load these conf.

2) change prefix in your ~/.tmux.conf

```
set -g prefix F13
```

3) fire xterm and tmux

```
$ tmux
```

Comment: Does this break usage of `Ctrl+,` in applications like Google Chrome where you can use `Ctrl+,` and `Ctrl+.` to switch between conversations on hangouts.google.com?

Comment: No, These configurations for Xterm only

Comment: Awesome. Would it work and make sense to map each combo to a unique function key past 12 so they can be used for other triggers and not just all send-prefix?