# Can C-: be bound in tmux?

Tags: tmux

I've tried to make a prefix-less keybinding for the tmux command line.  I've tried to do it with <kbd>control</kbd>,

```
bind-key -n C-: command-prompt
```

but I can only get it working with <kbd>option</kbd>

```
bind-key -n M-: command-prompt
```

The problem with using option is that it conflicts with an existing<sup>1</sup> keybinding in Zsh

```
"^[:" is describe-key-briefly
```

Is there any way to make the version with <kbd>control</kbd> work?

---

<sup>1</sup> I don't remember if that's a Zsh default or not.  By "existing" I am not saying that it is *not* something I added.  But that's not important.  Since it is something I have learned I don't want to change it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I set tmux hotkey as Ctrl-, that is, Ctrl+comma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9922497/how-can-i-set-tmux-hotkey-as-ctrl-that-is-ctrlcomma)

Comment: TL;DR: Probably not without messing with your terminal emulator. It is likely your terminal emulator does not send a distinct value for `C-:`. You can check what your terminal sends for certain keypresses with `sed -n l` (use Enter after a keypress to put it on it's own line, where `$` corresponds to the end of line character, and `C-c` will quite). For `C-:`, mine just sends a literal `:`.

Comment: You'll need to look into your terminal emulator settings to make it send a distinct value for `C-:` and then bind your tmux command to that value. This depends on your terminal and is best suited for [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: the other question doesn't directly answer this, no, but it gives a few clues that can get me back on track to solving the problem, and your comments are yet more focused and useful than the other question's answers.  Thanks!

Comment: You are right that the question does not directly answer yours, but I used it as a duplicate nonetheless because: 1. it lets future questioners know that this issue has been discussed and there is another question they can look at and 2. it attempts to close this question so that answerers don't spent time on it, as it is impossible to get an answer that solves your question with the information you've provided. It is not meant to be a mark against you, it's just meant to be information to future people viewing this question.

Comment: "it is impossible to get an answer that solves your question with the information you've provided".  What?????  If you need more information from me, ask me for more information.  What information is missing?  I'm using tmux 3.1b on macOS Sierra on a 2015 MBP with 16 GB and half a terabyte of SSD.  What else do you want to know? Do you need some settings from my .tmux.conf?

Comment: "1. it lets future questioners know that this issue has been discussed and there is another question they can look at"..... huhhhh?????   The question has been discussed here in the comments, but with no answer.   The other question's answers don't answer it, so why would you close it?  There is no logical reason to close it.  It's not a duplicate.

Comment: There is no accepted answer because the answer is "no". You cannot directly bind C-, or C-: in tmux, since most (possibly all) terminals will not send anything different than , or : in these cases. Everything I commented on your answer I learned from that question. There are workarounds that let you bind C-: to something in your terminal, but those are dependent on your setup and should be discussed in [SuperUser](https://superuser.com)